# How do you limit for-in loops in Javasript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

How can I limit for-in to 5 loops even if there are more properties in the object?

```
for(property in object){
    //do this stuff for the first 5 properties
}
```

Comment: for range 0 -> 4 ?

Answer (score 3):

Without counters:

```
Object.keys(object).slice(0,4).map((property) => { 
    // do something with property
})
```

Comment: I would use `forEach` instead of `map`, but I still like this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a counter. Something like this:

```
let counter = 0;
for(property in object)
{
  if (counter >= 5){
    break;
  }
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break;`

Like this

```
let props = 0;
for(property in object){
  //do this stuff for the first 5 properties
  props++;
  if (props > 4)
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object have a get method you can do

```
for (let index = 0; index <= 4; index++) {
  object.get(index);
}
```

otherwise you can use a counter

```
let counter = 0;
for (property in object) {
  // use property
  if (++counter == 5) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sniped very badly, but..) You can add a counter that then breaks the loop. Here is some code that works:

```
let i = 0;
for (property in object) {
    if (i++ == 5) {break;}
    //do this stuff for the first 5 properties
}
```

If you wish to not use a for-in loop, you can use to a regular for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < object.length && i < 5; i++) {
    var property = object[i];
    //do this stuff for the first 5 properties
}
```